# How can I print all the multiples of 5 from 5 to 1,000,000

Tags: python

New to Python and having a hard time creating a `for` loop or `while` loop that'll give me an output of `5, 10 ,15, 20, ...` all the way to `1,000,000`.

Comment: I think the python [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) object is what you want.

Comment: `print([i for i in range(5,1_000_000,5)])`

Answer (score 2):

Use `range` (note your doing to a million which is gonna take a while):

```
print(list(range(5,1000005,5)))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the "question" which explicitly "asks" for a `for` or `while` loop...

Answer (score 1):

```
total = 5
while total <= 1000000:
    print(total)
    total = total + 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`for i in range(0,1000000,5):
  print(i)`

This will print every time it goes up by 5.
The `range()` function works like `range(start, stop, step)`